# How do I develop a simple website that displays positive affirmations after every 3 seconds in javascript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have developed a practice website that will display affirmations after every 3 seconds using API in angular. It works fine but when I switch between tabs in browser, the affirmations goes fast.
How can I fix it?

```html
 ngOnInit(): void {
    let res = this.http.get('https://dulce-affirmations-api.herokuapp.com/affirmation/index');
    res.subscribe(data => {
      this.affirmationsData = data
      console.log(data);
      this.getRandomAffirmations()
    })

  }

  getRandomAffirmations() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.affirmationsData.length)

    // console.log(this);
    // console.log(this.affirmationsData[randomIndex].phrase)

    this.affirmation = this.affirmationsData[randomIndex].phrase

    let appComponentObj = this
    setInterval(function () { appComponentObj.getRandomAffirmations(); }, 3000);
  }
```

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  let res = this.http.get('https://dulce-affirmations-api.herokuapp.com/affirmation/index');
  res.subscribe(data => {
    this.affirmationsData = data
    console.log(data);
    this.getRandomAffirmations()
  })

}

getRandomAffirmations() {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.affirmationsData.length)

  this.affirmation = this.affirmationsData[randomIndex].phrase

  let appComponentObj = this
  setInterval(function() {
    appComponentObj.getRandomAffirmations();
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
{{affirmation}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recursively invoking an infinite number of `setInterval()`. Call `setInterval()` once outside of `getRandomAffirmations()`.

As an alternative fix, you can change `setInterval()` to `setTimeout()`.